# No BOOT folder found in EFI partition

Tags: bootcamp, partition, efi

Excuse me if this already have answers elsewhere.

My problem is that I cannot find the `BOOT` folder in `EFI` partition, the only thing exists is the `APPLE` folder. This is quite strange as I see in almost every post, they suggest the firmware needs to read the `BOOTx64.efi` to detect the bootable system.

I started diving into `EFI` partition because my Mac Mini 2018 did not show startup disk choices when I held down the `Option` key when starting, it just booted into macOS directly. But in macOS **System Preferences -> Startup Disk**, I can see my Windows BootCamp disk.

Any light to shed on me?

---

**The reason why my Mac did not respect my pressing on `Option` key has nothing to do with the `bootx64.efi`. It turned out to be the misbehavior  of my Logitech MX Keys. It never successfully sent the signal to Mac even though I was using the Unifying receiver. I changed to a cabled keyboard and everything worked fine.**

Comment: Which macOS is installed on your Mac Mini?

Comment: The boot file for macOS (that is read by the firmware) is not stored in an EFI partition.

Comment: @Alper It is the latest Monterey 12.6

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the information, I also saw in some posts which agree with you, But will that contributes to my stage where I cannot choose startup disk when starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macOS operating system looks at the files in the Windows partition to see if Windows is installed on your Mac. The macOS operating system does not look at the files in the `EFI` partition, as suggested by your question.

The full path, for the macOS boot file, is `/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi`.

When using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows, a `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` file is created. This file is the same as the `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi` file, which is also created when using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows.